# How to index element x in a python loop like this?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, indexing

Shouldn't be too hard to solve, just cannot wrap my head around it...

```
for x in range (1, len(df)):
     spatial_frequency.append(df.loc[:, ["Spatial Frequency [lp/mm]."]])
```

The goal is to store each "Spatial Frequency" in an array.
Writing each line like this works, but I want it in a loop

```
spatial_frequency[1] = df.loc[:, ["Spatial Frequency [lp/mm].1"]]
```

I want to loop from 1->length, and store each "spacial frequency" element in the array.
No combination of index formatting (".", "x") will work for me, can somebody assist?

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range (1, len(df)):
     spatial_frequency.append(df.loc[:, [f"Spatial Frequency [lp/mm].{x}"]])
```